# How to output the shell find result and the match number?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to use find command to find some string in files, and want to see the find result and the number of match line at the same time.

For example, use following command, I can get the find result, but I cannot know how many match result I have got.

```
find . -name .history  | xargs grep ls
```

the output is

```
ls -r
ls -R
ls
```

what I expect output is like this

```
ls -r
ls -R
ls
total match number: 3
```

How can I get my expect output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.... | awk '{ a+=1; print} END { print "total match number: " a}'
```

Comment: why not use NR ? ... | `awk '{ print } END { print "total match number: " NR }'`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative without awk is:

```
| tee >(cat) >(wc -l)
```

To give you the output and the number. If you really want the text also:

```
| tee >(cat) >(echo "total match number: "`wc -l`);
```